# BIRT OL start attribute ignored rendering PDF

Tags: html, css, pdf, birt

When I use the Ol with start option, It always displays as value 1 for each list item.  It renders well as an HTML, but not while generating a pdf document. I tried importing CSS style as well but no luck.

Please find the below content.

```
<p>Some intro text</p>

<ol>
<li>List Item 1</li>
</ol>

<ol start="2">
<li>Some text for list item 2</li>
</ol>

Expected the start number attribute to order the list correctly, as per the requirement.

PDF resulting in:
 1. List Item 1
 1. Some text for list item 2
 1. and So on..
```

Answer (score 0):

BIRT does not support all of HTML (and never will).
It is only meant for highlighting text.